# how to make my dns server public?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq, bind9

i'm trying to make a public DNS server , my DNS server works only on my internal network but when i try to 'nslookup example.com myDNSserverIP(public ip)' it fails

i'm running it on ubuntu 15.10-Server-32bit - dnsmasq 2.76

dnsmasq config file :

```
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.personal
interface=wlan0
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
log-queries
```

and resolv.personal :

```
nameserver 'MyPublicIP'
nameserver  8.8.4.4
```

I opened ports with Gufw firewall i allow in-out port 53 upd and tcp , also opened it in my router '[canyouseeme](http://canyouseeme.org)' says that port 53 is open
, i allowed IP forwarding

notice : i tried to make with bind and maraDNS also failed

so what should i do to make it public ?!

Comment: Public recursive DNS servers may be subject to DNS amplification attacks so may not be the best thing to try to run (unless you restrict or rate throttle queries from The Internet...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bind9 and configure it to not answer recursive queries.  This can be done as a split brain configuration responding one way to the Internet, and allowing recursive responses from your network.

Running `dnsmasq` and `bind9` on the same server takes a bit of doing.  You likely don't want bind9 listening on an interface that dnsmasq is serving.

This is a bind9 view definition for external users.

```
view "external-in" in {
    // Our external (untrusted) view. We permit any client to access
    // portions of this view. We do not perform recursion or cache
    // access for hosts using this view.

    match-clients { any; };
    allow-query { none; };                  // Secure queries
    recursion no;                           // Secure cache
    additional-from-auth yes;
    additional-from-cache yes;

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zones";
```

Comment: Also, open the firewall :)

Comment: @sandyp  Make sure you get recursion disabled first, then open your firewall.